# Why does flex-direction: row only work when I set the element to display: inline-block?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The `flex-direction:row` is only working when I add `display: inline-block` inside `nav li{}`. I know it because `-webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;` is working. But other properties like `justify-content: space-between;` are not working.

And the opposite; if I remove `display: inline-block` inside `nav li{}`, then only `flex-direction:column` is working. What is the problem?

```css
nav{
    background: grey;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}

nav li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a><li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>   
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

It only gives you the illusion that it works.

Flex set at the `<nav>` level makes the `<ul>` a flex item, and doesn't affect `<li>` elements.

You want the Flex container to be `<ul>`.